# Passing Parameters through URL Power Bi Embed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powerbi-embedded

I am still not very comfortable using with Power Bi and how it works, and I was asked to create a webpage using AppOwnsData using ASP.Net MVC where it would display a Power Bi Report, and on its side have some text boxes where the user could input data and that data would work as a parameter. The problem is to pass that data to Power Bi, and at first I though to pass it through the URL when the API is called, But I can't Find anything Related with this online.
If Someone could Help it would greatly Appreciated.

Happy coding!

Comment: What code have you tried? Please add it to your question.

Comment: When embedding Power BI, filters are managed through the API, not via the URL. See [Control report filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters).

Comment: @iamdlm I haven't Start Coding yet, Im still trying to figure out how I can build this.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov By using Filters if I got users from two different places they will be able to see each others data right? Is there any way I can get over that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in Power BI service, by passing parameters you can filter the report by data field. Add the following to the end of the URL in Power BI service:

Syntax for adding the filter in URL:

```js
URL?filter=Table_Name/Data_Field_Name eq 'value'
```

For example:

Filtering by `Region`.

URL?filter=Region/Region eq 'New England'

The end of URL will look like this:

[image]

For more information regarding the URL filters, please refer below link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/updates/power-bi-embedded-query-parameters-api/

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters

Comment: Just for everyones info this merely filters the existing data.  SO the idea is dump all the data into the report without any filtering and then use the params in the URL to do the filtering.  I'm looking into query parameters but I haven't figured out how to pass a parameter to the query yet.